# mod_auth_form and cross-domain authentication

Tags: apache-2.4

I have two sites: `app1.example.com` and `app2.someotherexample.com` and I'd like to use mod_auth_form to authenticate users. I'd like to let users log in on anyone of the two sites without needing to log in a second time on the other one. Both sites are hosted by the same apache. Is this somehow possible?